# Iterating Over Orders to Capture and Organize Time Values

Tags: python

I have a list of orders that the "for" loop is iterating over for a list of times the order was placed. Variable "ordertime" is the where the time is stored. I would like to do a match using the "if" statement, then write it to a corresponding column in either pandas or to a csv (ie. 12pm) with a value of "1" then get a total of the number of times someone ordered at that particular time. Is there an easier way to compile this total, maybe using a list? I'm not sure how to structure the logic. Below is what I have so far. This successfully prints out all the times. The way it is currently structured, I would have to create an "if" statement for all times 12 pm, 1 pm, 2 pm etc. I'm sure there's a better way.

```
    for time in orders: 
        ordertime = time.text

        ordertime = re.sub(':\d+', '', ordertime)

        if ordertime == ("12 pm"):

            print(ordertime)

        else:
            pass
```

Comment: what is the input `Order`, what is the expected output

Comment: post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for us to try your code

Comment: That was a typo. I corrected the code to show print(ordertime)

Comment: I can't tell what it is you want.  You have a collection of strings, and you can extract an order time from those strings.  You want to loop over those strings and......???? - Also, as an aside, you shouldn't be iterating over something called 'Order'.  Capital first letter names are used for types. Lowercase first letter names denote objects/values.  Also, things you're iterating over are often pluralized. (ie: change 'Order' to 'orders' or 'ordertimes' maybe?)

Comment: Sorry, not a python expert or even a programmer. I'm learning as I go. I'll change the code to you preference.

I want to loop over the "orders" and get a time from each order and categorize it in a db value so I can add them all up. I want to see which times of the day has the most orders. I want to know how many times "12pm, 1pm, 3pm" is being abstracted from orders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I get the basic idea you're trying to get to.  Here's code that is similar to yours, but names things more correctly and fills in all the missing parts so that it is runnable. This is what is meant by a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This builds up a dictionary called `ordertimes` that gives you counts of the number of times something was ordered at each particular time:

```
import re
from collections import defaultdict

class Order:
    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text

orders = [
    Order('9 am:12345'),
    Order('4 pm:43434'),
    Order('7 pm:45454'),
    Order('11 am:33'),
    Order('9 am:5454'),
    Order('4 pm:6666'),
]

ordertimes = defaultdict(int)

for order in orders:

    ordertime = order.text
    ordertime = re.sub(':\d+', '', ordertime)
    ordertimes[ordertime] += 1

for time in ordertimes:
    print(time + ': ' + str(ordertimes[time]))
```

Result:

```
9 am: 2
4 pm: 2
7 pm: 1
11 am: 1
```

Comment: Thanks Steve, what do the numbers behind 9 am: "12345" represent in the dictionary?

Comment: You tell me.  I just read your code and saw that your were stripping off a ':' + some number of digits to get the time part of your string. - This code does not process that part of each item, as your code didn't either.

Comment: It was displaying 9:01 am, 4:32pm, etc. I didn't need the exact times, just the rounded times.

Comment: Thanks Steve, I'll give it a go and test it out. I appreciate the help!!

Comment: then how do you get the 'am/pm' part?  I wouldn't think that your times would look like 9 am:01, 4 pm:32, etc., which is what your code is assuming so that you can possibly extract a value of "12 pm".  See, this is the problem with you forming an incomplete question.  We aren't mind readers.  There's no way to know what that value represented or how it was formatted.

Comment: It exports the time as 9:01 am, but I needed to keep the am/pm since it's regular time and not military time. I just needed to remove the :01 using regex.